# How to update JSF SelectManyListBox items from selected item in SelectOneMenu?

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have the following components:

```
                     <h:selectOneMenu id="company" 
                                 value="#{companyController.selected.companyId}" 
                                 onchange="?????????">

                    <f:selectItems value="#{companyController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel value="some value" for="locations" />

                <h:selectManyListbox id="locations" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{companyController.selected.locationCollection}"/>
                </h:selectManyListbox>
```

Every time a company is selected in the SelectOneMenu i need to update the items in the SelectManyListBox.

Please Help me

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use `<f:ajax>`.  Perhaps something like this:

```
            <h:selectOneMenu id="company" 
                             value="#{companyController.selected.companyId}">
                <f:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this" render="@this locations" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{companyController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputLabel value="some value" for="locations" />

            <h:selectManyListbox id="locations" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{companyController.selected.locationCollection}"/>
            </h:selectManyListbox>
```

Then you could modify your `selected` objects `setCompanyId` method to update the `locationCollection`:

```
public void setCompanyId( long companyId ) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
    // now update your location collection
    this.locationCollection = locationCollectionMap.get( companyId );
}
```